# how to close a workbook if using wb.name like

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please help closing a workbook where "like" was used when opening as the sample below?

```
Dim wb As Workbook
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
If wb.Name Like "SHIPPING LIST*" Then wb.Activate
Next wb
Columns("A:I").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("PRIORITIES TEMPLATE - SHIPPING LIST.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("xyz - abc").Select
Range("A1").Select
Sheets("xyz - abc").Paste
```

Comment: doesn't wb.close work?

Comment: Where are you trying to close it?

Comment: There are several issues with your code - main one being that you need to hold on to a reference to the workbook & worksheet objects you're working with. `Activate` and `Select` are evil. Also, what if more than one opened workbook names start with "SHIPPING LIST"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :
(Got rid of useless and memory-greedy "select" and "activate")

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim WbName as String

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name Like "SHIPPING LIST*" Then
        wb.Sheets(1).Columns("A:I").Copy
Destination:=Workbooks("PRIORITIES TEMPLATE - SHIPPING LIST.xlsm").Sheets("xyz - abc").Range("A1")
        wb.Close
    Else

    End if


    Next wb
```

If `wb.Name Like "SHIPPING LIST*"` doesn't work (never used it in VBA...), use `Instr(1, wb.Name, "SHIPPING LIST")<>0 then`

Comment: thank you. It's having me debug once it gets to wb.Columns("A:I").Copy. could you please help?

Comment: It's because we needed to specify te worksheets that were using. Is it good now?

Comment: thank you. I specified the worksheets. Debug now moved down to: Windows("PRIORITIES TEMPLATE - SHIPPING LIST.xlsm").Sheets("xyz - abc").Range("A1").Paste

Comment: Plz specify the error message, it is useful to identify. Best guess just switch `Windows("` to `Workbooks("` , if not enough check the edit.